# Retrieving row from MySQL Database via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, row

Please bear with me, I'm new here - and I'm just starting out with PHP. To be honest, this is my first project, so please be merciful. :)

```
    $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT message FROM data WHERE code = '". (int) $code ."'         LIMIT 1"));
    echo $row['message'];
```

Would this be enough to fetch the message from the database based upon a pre-defined '$code' variable? I have already successfully connected to the database.

This block of code seems to return nothing - just a blank space. :(

I would be grateful of any suggestions and help. :)

UPDATE:

Code now reads:

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
   // Start MySQL Connection
    REMOVED FOR SECURITY
    // Check if code exists
    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT code FROM data WHERE code = '$code'"))){
    echo 'Hooray, that works!';
    $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT message FROM data WHERE code = '". (int) $code     ."' LIMIT 1")) or die(mysql_error());
    echo $row['message'];
    }
    else {
    echo 'That code could not be found. Please try again!';
    }
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to add `or die(mysql_error());` to the end of your query.

Comment: If you're just learning, look for tutorials that use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements rather than the old, deprecated MySQL interface

Comment: @njk See above reply, also - the rest of the code is not being executed, so that part of my code is obviously defective.

Comment: @user1867357 Are your errors being suppressed? Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before this code.

Comment: @user1867357 Please delete your comment. Update your question with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best not to chain functions together like this since if the query fails the fetch will also appear to fail and cause an error message that may not actually indicate what the real problem was.

Also, don't wrap quotes around integer values in your SQL queries.

```
if(! $rs = mysql_query("SELECT message FROM data WHERE code = ". (int) $code ." LIMIT 1") ) {
    die('query failed! ' . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
echo $row['message'];
```

And the standard "don't use `mysql_*` functions because deprecated blah blah blah"...

If you're still getting a blank response you might want to check that you're not getting 0 rows returned. Further testing would also include `echo`ing out the query to see if it's formed properly, and running it yourself to see if it's returning the correct data.

Comment: It is now only displaying the first message in the database, regardless of the codes. :(

Comment: Well, I seem to have gone on the assumption that the `code` column in your database is an `INTEGER` datatype. If it's a `CHAR`/`VARCHAR`/etc then you *will* want to wrap it in single quotes. Other than that you'll need to `echo` the query and test.

Comment: Wrap which part in single quotes? Thanks for all your help, by the way. :)

Comment: `SELECT message FROM data WHERE code = 1 LIMIT 1` if the column `code` is a numeric type, `SELECT message FROM data WHERE code = '1' LIMIT 1` if it is a string type.

Comment: It is a VARCHAR type. I replaced `SELECT message FROM data WHERE code = ". (int) $code ." LIMIT 1` with `SELECT message FROM data WHERE code = '1' LIMIT 1`

Comment: Fixed, thanks anyway. I really appreciate your help - you've given me a great head start. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

1. Don't use `mysql_*`.  It's deprecated. use either [mysqli_*](https://www.php.net/mysqli) functions or the [PDO Library](https://www.php.net/pdo)
2. Whenever you enter a value into a query (here, `$code`), use either [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [PDO's quote](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) function to prevent SQL injection
3. Always check for errors.

Example using PDO:

```
//connect to database
$user = 'dbuser';  //mysql user name
$pass = 'dbpass';  //mysql password
$db   = 'dbname';  //name of mysql database
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$db;
try {
    $con = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Could not connect to database: ' . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

//escape code to prevent SQL injection
$code = $con->quote($code);
//prepare the SQL string
$sql = 'SELECT message FROM data WHERE code='.$code.' LIMIT 1';
//do the sql query
$res = $con->query($sql);
if(!$res) {
    echo "something wrong with the query!";
    echo $sql; //for development only; don't output SQL in live server!
    die();
}
//get result
$row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//output result
print_r($row);
```